# how to display text in same sweetalert box after clicking on confirm button?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I want to display the message in same sweet alert box after clicking on confirm button. I do not know how to do it. After the excel sheet is loaded successfully , i am displaying sweet alert again saying 
"successfully invited". But before the i want to display message in same alert box after clicking on confirm until it loads and calls for other alert. Kindly help me out.

```
$('.uploadinvitee-btn').click(function(){
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                cancelButtonColor: "#ccc",
                cancelButtonText: "No",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: true,
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                text : "Please do not refresh the page",
                showTextOnConfirm : true
            },

            function(){
            var formData = new FormData( $('#uploadInvitee-form')[0]);
                //alert("please do not refresh page until the excel sheet loads completely...!!");
               // setTimeout(function() { alert("please do not refresh page until the excel sheet loads completely...!!"); }, 1000);
            $.ajax({
                url : baseURL+'InviteeUpload/uploadInvitees',
                type : 'POST',
                data : formData,
                //async : false,
                cache : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                success : function(response) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(response);
                    if(result.result == 1){

                        swal({
                            title: "Success",
                            text: result.message,
                            confirmButtonColor: "#2196F3"
                        },
                        function(isConfirm){
                            if (isConfirm) {
                                window.location.href =baseURL+"event";
                            }
                        });
                    } else if(result.result == 0){
                        swal({
                            title: "Attention!",
                            text: result.message,
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                            closeOnConfirm: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        swal({
                            title: "Oops!",
                            text: "Something went wrong! Please check the excel you have uploaded.",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                            closeOnConfirm: true
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: New content after confirming? That's not how people are used to use a confirm box.

Comment: I agree with you. But my manager wanted to be like this. i am a backend developer so i am just trying my best .

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to open a new modal to the same place as the previous modal was?

Comment: Did you try with promise?

Comment: @Teemu okie...I will try...

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena no... i did not

Comment: [This](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#ajax-requests) is what you are looking for. You're welcome ;)

Comment: Or may be [this one](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-dom-nodes-as-content)